# insert ( *) between two variables in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have the equation:

```
f:= x^2y^2+ 5xyz
```

I need to write this equation like:

```
f:= x^2*y^2+ 5*x*y*z
```

I have used replace space to `*` but it does not  work properly.

Comment: You say you tried something. Please include it into your question, and describe what went wrong.

Comment: I need to insert * between the variables and between the variable and value.

Comment: From what I see, you want to insert `*` between any digit/letter. So, what was that you tried?

Comment: I have used replace blank to *

Comment: yes this is what I tried Wiktor.

Comment: Blank? You mean a space?

Comment: Ok, try `\w(?=\w)` --> `$&*`

Comment: you mean I can do this from Replace

Comment: and blank mean space

Comment: I have tried replace but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex based search and replace:

*Find What*: `[[:alnum:]](?=[[:alnum:]])`
*Replace With*: `$&*`

**Details**:

- `[[:alnum:]]` - an alphanumeric that is followed by...
- `(?=[[:alnum:]])` - another alphanumeric (`(?=...)` is a positive lookahead that tests for a pattern match, and if there is a match, returns true, else false).

The `$&` is the backreference to the whole match.

[image]